# R- set working directory to hdfs

Tags: r, out-of-memory, working-directory, revolution-r

I need to create some data frames from very large data sets in R.  Is there a way to change my working directory so that R objects that I create are saved into hdfs? I don't have enough space under /home to save these large data frames, but I need to use a few data frame functions that require a data frame as input.

Comment: Maybe a silly comment but: Does `setwd()` works for your purposes?

Comment: Most functions will also allow you to save the object anywhere, without moving the `getwd()` folder.

Comment: SabDeM: the setwd() function can point to different folders in the local directory, but it cannot access folders stored on other machines (which is what I'm asking)

Roman: How would I create a data object in hdfs? Right now I have an XDF file sitting in cloudera and I would like to create a non-local data frame from it.  Right now, I use rxCopyToLocal() to copy the hdfs file to the local compute context, then I use rxXdfToDataFrame to turn the file into a data frame.  How could I save this data frame on hdfs rather than in my /home folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using data frame to do some operations on data from hdfs, we are technically using memory not the disk space. So the limiting factor will be memory(RAM) not the available disk space in any working directory and changing working directory wont make too much sense.

You don't need to copy the file from hdfs to local compute context to process it as dataframe.

Use rxReadXdf() to directly convert the xdf dataset to a dataframe in hdfs itself.

something like this(assuming you are in hadoop compute context):

```
airDS <- RxTextData(file="/data/revor/AirlineDemoSmall.csv", fileSystem=hdfFS)
# making a text data source from a csv file at above hdfs location 
# hdfsFS is the object storing hadoop fileSystem details using RxHdfsFileSyStem() 

airxdf <- RxXdfData(file= "/data/AirlineXdf")
# specifying the location to create the composite xdf file in hdfs
# make sure this location exits in hdfs


airXDF <- rxImport(inFile=airDS, outFile=airxdf)
# Importing csv to composite xdf 


airDataFrame <- rxReadXdf(file=airXDF)

# Now airDataFrame is a dataframe in memory 
# use class(airDataframe) to double check
# do your required operations on this data frame
```

Comment: Thank you this works (although it takes a while)!  Can you explain to me why rxReadXdf doesn't run into a RAM space issue where as using rxHadoopCopyToLocal then rxXdfToDataFrame does?